# How to make recursive calls using Perl, awk or sed?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

If a .cpp or .h file has #includes (e.g. #include "ready.h"), I need to make a text file that has these filenames on it.  Since ready.h may have its own #includes, the calls have to be made recursively. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Since *ready.h* may have its own `# include'`s, the calls have to **behave** recursively, which means you can simply stack data during the process.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: A simple way to do this is to maintain a list, in which you add the entries you find, and loop considering the condition as `while (list not empty); do $(something with last element of list); $(insert new element at the end of list); ...; done`. But, if you're trying to generate dependency trees, I don't know how, but there must be something already coined for this purpose.

Comment: It's a homework problem, we are learning scripting languages at the same time we are given this problem.  I don't know what this code looks like because I'm not familiar with scripting languages yet.  What I'm trying to do is learn the languages in time for midterm, but this homework problem, I don't know how to code it yet.  If someone knows how to code this, I could then understand it.

Comment: Ah I didn't see its a homework problem.    The answer I put below will work but you might want to do it with a "sub" instead of calling system()    Perl recursion work pretty much the same as every other language,  the only difference is Perl has the "local" keyword,  which I'd avoid -- stick to "my" unless you've been around a while.     Also what you are trying to do is a graph search (BFS or DFS),  but you'll probably learn that terminology later.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of @OneSolitaryNoob will likely work allright, but has an issue: for each recursion, it starts another process, which is quite wasteful. We can use subroutines to do that more efficiently. Assuming that all header files are in the working directory:

```
sub collect_recursive_includes {
  # Unpack parameter from subroutine
  my ($filename, $seen) = @_;
  # Open the file to lexically scoped filehandle
  # In your script, you'll probably have to transform $filename to correct path
  open my $fh, "<", $filename or do {
    # On failure: Print a warning, and return. I.e. go on with next include
    warn "Can't open $filename: $!";
    return;
  };
  # Loop through each line, recursing as needed
  LINE: while(<$fh>) {
    if (/^\s*#include\s+"([^"]+)"/) {
      my $include = $1;
      # you should probably normalize $include before testing if you've seen it
      next LINE if $seen->{$include}; # skip seen includes
      $seen->{$include} = 1;
      collect_recursive_includes($include, $seen);
    }
  }
}
```

This subroutine remembers what files it has already seen, and avoids recursing there again—each file is visited one time only.

At the top level, you need to provide a hashref as second argument, that will hold all filenames as keys after the sub has run:

```
my %seen = ( $start_filename => 1 );
collect_recursive_includes($start_filename, \%seen);

my @files = sort keys %seen;
# output @files, e.g. print "$_\n" for @files;
```

I hinted in the code comments that you'll probabably have to normalize the filenames. E.g consider a starting filename `./foo/bar/baz.h`, which points to `qux.h`. Then the actual filename we wan't to recurse to is `./foo/bar/qux.h`, not `./qux.h`. The [`Cwd`](https://metacpan.org/module/Cwd) module can help you find your current location, and to transform relative to absolute paths. The [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) module is a lot more complex, but has good support for platform-independent filename and -path manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, recursion is straightforward:

```
sub factorial
{
    my $n = shift;
    if($n <= 1)
        { return 1; }
    else
        { return $n * factorial($n - 1); }
}

print factorial 7;     # prints 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Offhand, I can think of only two things that require care:

- In Perl, variables are global by default, and therefore static by default. Since you don't want one function-call's variables to trample another's, you need to be sure to localize your variables, e.g. by using `my`.
- There are some limitations with prototypes and recursion. If you want to use prototypes (e.g. `sub factorial($)` instead of just `sub factorial`), then you need to provide the prototype *before* the function definition, so that it can be used within the function body. (Alternatively, you can use `&` when you call the function recursively; that will prevent the prototype from being applied.)

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear what you want the display to look like,  but the basic would be a script called follow_includes.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while(<>) {
      if(/\#include "(\S+)\"/) {
         print STDOUT $1 . "\n";
         system("./follow_includes.pl $1");
      }
}
```

Run it like:

```
% follow_includes.pl somefile.cpp
```

And if you want to hide any duplicate includes,  run it like:

```
% follow_includes.pl somefile.cpp | sort -u
```

Usually you'd want this in some sort of tree-print.

Comment: select my answer if you like it :)